# Can we create a table in django without models class?

Tags: python, django, database

I need to dynamically create database tables depending on user requirements. so apart from a few predefined databases, all other databases should be created at runtime after taking table characteristics(like no of cols, primary key etc.) from user.

I read a bit of docs, and know about django.db.connection but all examples there are only for adding data to a database, not creating tables. (ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)

So is there anyway to create tables without models in django, this condition is a must, so if not possible with django, which other framework should I look at?

note: I am not good at writing questions, ask if any other info is needed.

Thanks!

Comment: See [*Executing custom SQL directly*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly), but usually creating custom databases is *not* necessary, usually by linearizing data one can overcome this issue and store the data in a finer granuality form.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inspectdb` to automatically generate the models from the legacy database. You can check about it in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/legacy-databases/).

Or you can use SQL directly. Although, you will have to process the tables in python. Check it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I dont have databases, i will be creating tables on the go